# How can I declare own methods in QTest test class?

Tags: c++, methods, qtestlib

Is it possible to declare a method in a `QTest` class (that extends `QObject` and uses the `QOBJECT` macro) which won't be executed by the framework, but can be used to bundle repeating routines?

When I try to declare a `void` method inside this class, the compiler reports a missing type specifier. Apparently this is usually a namespace issue, but using namespace `std` causes the meta object compiler to fail.

Comment: show your code and errormessages of what you tried so far.

Comment: And even if you haven't written any code, show us some pseudocode that illustrates what you are trying to achieve.